# data structure similar to array but supporting deletion

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am thinking of the following data structure question:

given integers between `1` and `n` in sorted order, every operation queries and then removes (in a single call) `k`th smallest number. How to make the query and removal both constant time operations?

It is similar to an array structure but requiring constant removing. Though an order balanced binary tree can do this, but it is `O(lg n)` complexity.

Can one take the advantage of the range property (numbers only between `1` and `n`) to make it work?

Comment: When you say "removes the kth smallest number", do you in fact mean it always removes, say, the 3rd smallest number?  That's the usual interpretation of what you've written.  But do you perhaps mean instead that the `i`th query supplies some value `k_i`, and we must report and remove the `k_i`th smallest number?

Comment: no, i meant to say "remove 2nd" in one operation, "remove 5th" in another.

Comment: Seems like impossible. You have to do some trade-offs. And profide more information. How big is `n`? How much queries? Are you concerned about memory?

Answer (score 1):

[LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) is what you are looking for . If you want index as in arrays then use this [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). But you need to insert them in order from `1` to`n`

Comment: How are you going to remove the k-th number in O(1)?

Comment: Yes this could only give u constant query time . But not constant removal time . Thanks for alerting @Dukeling .

Answer (score 1):

What is the maximal value of `N`? You mentioned that you are going to work with positive numbers - [Van Emde Boas tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree) probably the best choice for you.

Short description:
- allows to store only positive numbers from [0,2^k), where k is is a number of bits required to store maximal number `N`. 
 - all operations (insert,delete,lookup,find_next,find_prev) works in `log(K)`.**Not log(N). So, for integer 32-bit numbers complexity is log(32)=5**
 
 - disadvantage is memory consumption. requires `2^k ~ O(N)` memory, so for storing integers you need ~1GB RAM. **Remember, that usually O(N) memory means O(number of elements) but here it means O(maximal stored value).**

Note: I'm not sure about supporting k-th element query but description looks nice:

> FindNext: find the key/value pair with the smallest key at least a
>   given k
>
> FindPrevious: find the key/value pair with the largest key at most a
>   given k

**UPDATE**

As Dukeling mentioned below, K-th element query is not supported. I see the only way to implement it.

```
int x = getMin();
for(int i=0;i<k-1;i++) x = getNext(x);
```

after this loop x will store k-th element. But complexity is `O(K*log(bits))`. Too bad for large values of K(

Comment: k-th element querying is a pretty significant part of the requirements (and no, those listed operations don't really appear to help much).